# Recommended format for storing videos to be read in CNTK

Tags: video, recurrent-neural-network, cntk

I want to test a recurrent model on a small subset of videos from the UCF11 dataset. Is there a recommended format for video files? Is it sufficient to convert the frames from the videos to numpy arrays and then store them in the CTF format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend storing them in CTF format; it's too verbose, especially for dense data. If you have them as numpy arrays you can just feed them directly, or you can just follow [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/v2.1/Examples/Video/GettingStarted/Python/Conv3D_UCF11.py)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by too verbose and why that's bad? In that example, each time a video file is loaded, we have to select the frames and then process each one. If I preprocessed all the frames I want from the videos and stored as CTF, that penalty would be gone (given, I'd be left with a very large file).

Comment: By verbose I mean exactly what you said: it's going to be a very large file. It's non bad per-se, but I would expect going to disk is slow. But it all depends on the processing you do before writing the frames to CTF. You might want to check out this converter from CTF to binary format, and replace your CTFDeserializer with a CBFDeserializer: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/v2.1/Scripts/ctf2bin.py